# 2D linear interpolation: data and interpolated points

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, linear-interpolation, mplot3d

Consider this y(x) function:

[image]

where we can generate these scattered points in a file: `dataset_1D.dat`:

```
# x   y   
0   0
1   1
2   0
3   -9
4   -32
```

The following is a 1D interpolation code for these points:

1. Load this scattered points
2. Create a `x_mesh`
3. Perform a 1D interpolation

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d, interp1d, interpnd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Load the data:    
x, y  = np.loadtxt('./dataset_1D.dat', skiprows = 1).T

# Create the function Y_inter for interpolation:
Y_inter = interp1d(x,y)

# Create the x_mesh:    
x_mesh = np.linspace(0, 4, num=10)
print x_mesh

# We calculate the y-interpolated of this x_mesh :   
Y_interpolated = Y_inter(x_mesh)
print Y_interpolated

# plot:

plt.plot(x_mesh, Y_interpolated, "k+")
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
plt.legend(['Linear 1D interpolation', 'data'], loc='lower left',  prop={'size':12})
plt.xlim(-0.1, 4.2)
plt.grid()
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.show()
```

This plots the following:

[image]

Now, consider this z(x,y) function:

[image]

where we can generate these scattered points in a file: `dataset_2D.dat` :

```
# x    y    z
0   0   0
1   1   0
2   2   -4
3   3   -18
4   4   -48
```

In this case we would have to perform a 2D interpolation:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d, interp2d, interpnd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Load the data:
x, y, z  = np.loadtxt('./dataset_2D.dat', skiprows = 1).T

# Create the function Z_inter for interpolation:
Z_inter = interp2d(x, y, z)

# Create the x_mesh and y_mesh :
x_mesh = np.linspace(1.0, 4, num=10)
y_mesh = np.linspace(1.0, 4, num=10)
print x_mesh
print y_mesh

# We calculate the z-interpolated of this x_mesh and y_mesh :
Z_interpolated = Z_inter(x_mesh, y_mesh)
print Z_interpolated
print type(Z_interpolated)
print Z_interpolated.shape

# plot: 
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')
plt.legend(['data'], loc='lower left',  prop={'size':12})
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

plt.show()
```

This plots the following:

[image]

where the scattered data is shown again in red dots, to be consistent with the 2D plot.

1. I do not know how to interpret the  `Z_interpolated` result:

   According to the printing lines for the above code, 
   `Z_interpolated` is a n-dimensional numpy array, of shape (10,10). In other words, a 2D matrix with 10 rows and 10 columns.

I would have expected an interpolated `z[i]` value for each value of `x_mesh[i]` and `y_mesh[i]` Why I do not receive this ?

2. How could I plot also in the 3D plot the interpolated data (just like the black crosses in the 2D plot)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpretation of `Z_interpolated`: your 1-D `x_mesh` and `y_mesh` defines a [mesh on which to interpolate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.__call__.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d.__call__). Your 2-D interpolation return `z` is therefore a 2D array with shape (len(y), len(x)) which matches `np.meshgrid(x_mesh, y_mesh)`. As you can see, your z[i, i], instead of z[i], is the expected value for `x_mesh[i]` and `y_mesh[i]`. And it just has a lot more, all values on the mesh.

A potential plot to show all interpolated data:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d

# Your original function
x = y = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zz = 2 * (xx ** 2) - (xx ** 3) - (yy ** 2)

# Your scattered points
x = y = np.arange(0, 5)
z = [0, 0, -4, -18, -48]

# Your interpolation
Z_inter = interp2d(x, y, z)
x_mesh = y_mesh = np.linspace(1.0, 4, num=10)
Z_interpolated = Z_inter(x_mesh, y_mesh)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
# Plot your original function
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz, color='b', alpha=0.5)
# Plot your initial scattered points
ax.scatter(x, y, z, color='r', marker='o')
# Plot your interpolation data
X_real_mesh, Y_real_mesh = np.meshgrid(x_mesh, y_mesh)
ax.scatter(X_real_mesh, Y_real_mesh, Z_interpolated, color='g', marker='^')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In my post I was using `interp2d` in order to use a better, cubic interpolation. By implementing this in your code,  `Z_inter = interp2d(x, y, z, kind='cubic')` it does not work, do you know why ? Thanks

Comment: Just changing the line `Z_inter = interp2d(x, y, z)` in my example code won't work. According to the "Notes" of [`scipy.interpolate.interp2d()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html), the "minimum number of data points required along the interpolation axis is (k+1)**2, with k=1 for linear, k=3 for cubic and k=5 for quintic interpolation". Just to make it work, change `x` and `y` to `x = y = np.arange(0, 20)` and change `z` to `z = 2 * (x ** 2) - (x ** 3) - (y ** 2)`. If this is not the reason, please let me know what errors you got.

Answer (score 1):

You would need two steps of interpolation. The first interpolates between y data. And the second interpolates between z data. You then plot the `x_mesh` with the two interpolated arrays.

```
x_mesh = np.linspace(0, 4, num=16)

yinterp = np.interp(x_mesh, x, y)
zinterp = np.interp(x_mesh, x, z)

ax.scatter(x_mesh, yinterp, zinterp, c='k', marker='s')
```

In the complete example below I added some variation in y direction as well to make the solution more general.

```
u = u"""# x    y    z
0   0   0
1   3   0
2   9   -4
3   16   -18
4   32   -48"""

import io
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Load the data:
x, y, z  = np.loadtxt(io.StringIO(u), skiprows = 1, unpack=True)

x_mesh = np.linspace(0, 4, num=16)

yinterp = np.interp(x_mesh, x, y)
zinterp = np.interp(x_mesh, x, z)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(x_mesh, yinterp, zinterp, c='k', marker='s')
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')
plt.legend(['data'], loc='lower left',  prop={'size':12})
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

plt.show()
```

[image]

For using `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` the solution is essentially the same:

```
u = u"""# x    y    z
0   0   0
1   3   0
2   9   -4
3   16   -18
4   32   -48"""

import io
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Load the data:
x, y, z  = np.loadtxt(io.StringIO(u), skiprows = 1, unpack=True)

x_mesh = np.linspace(0, 4, num=16)

fy = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')
fz = interp1d(x, z, kind='cubic')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(x_mesh, fy(x_mesh), fz(x_mesh), c='k', marker='s')
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')
plt.legend(['data'], loc='lower left',  prop={'size':12})
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, `np.interp` only allows linear interpolation. That is the reason why I was using `scipy`'s `interp1d`, in order to better fit to `z(x,y)`, which is cubic in `x`. Following your indications, and translating this to `interp1d`, we would: 1) Interpolate between y data: `Y_inter = interp1d(x,y, kind='cubic')` and 2) Interpolate between z data: `Z_inter = interp1d(x,z, kind='cubic')`. Then, we could do `Z_interpolated = Z_inter(x_mesh, y_mesh)` (my post), but this does not give the right answer... How could we achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Thank you, I am digging into this